# Subprocess in script doesn't work, when started manually it does

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, subprocess, pymssql

I have a script that reads from an mssql database and passes the read data to a subprocess of `some.exe`.
The data fetching works, fine but as soon as it is supposed to start `proc = subprocess.(["C:\\absolute\\path\\some.exe ", fetched_data]) proc.wait()` it seems to skip it and goes on for the next *"fetched_data"*.. I also tried to use `subprocess.call(["C:\\absolute\\path\\some.exe ", fetched_data])`

If I start `python` in the console (windows cmd) and do the exact same thing it works.

Why does calling the subprocess in the script not work and if issued manually in the console it does?

---

**edit:** The problem was that the subprocess started in the script again used `another.exe`, which couldn't be found by the subprocess (as the it used the python path). When started from directory where `some.exe` and `another.exe` are, the script runs fine.

Comment: Are you certain that the same version of python is being used in each case? Some people have multiple pythons in their computer.

Comment: do you have your entire code? Are you sure your code is actually going to the subprocess line? Have a `print "test"` to confirm it is actually going subprocess line

Comment: @Paul yes, I've explicitly checked that. @sumshi I can post the code, but I've figured that it's not necessary. I've put a print before and after the subprocess calling and it's printed without delay or output of `some.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fetched_data is an additional argument therefore:

```
proc = subprocess.call(["C:\\absolute\\path\\some.exe ", fetched_data])
```

It's an argument LIST not a string, what subprocess expects.

Comment: You're right, this is how I have it in the code, so that can't be the error. But thank you.

Comment: so `some.exe` does not get called, or it does not return anything?

Comment: I just checked that an apparently it returns the error level 2. If I run `some.exe` with the same arguments in cmd it does not.. so it's a problem with the syntax of the argument in the script for sure. thank you for leading me there.

Comment: Typo: `subprocess.(` is missing a method